# ¿Existen palabras en español que puedan ser usadas tanto como adjetivos, sustantivos y verbos?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, adjetivos

En inglés existen palabras que pueden ser usadas tanto como adjetivos, sustantivos o verbos. Por ejemplo "water". "Water" puede ser sustantivo en el agua, puede ser verbo cuando se usa como "regar" o puede ser un adjetivo en "water sports" (deportes acuáticos). ¿Existen palabras así en español?

Conozco palabras que pueden ser adjetivos o sustantivos: por ejemplo, la *lógica* como sustantivo o como adjetivo en "Es una idea lógica". O palabras que pueden ser sustantivos o verbos, por ejemplo "A él le gusta jugar" o "El jugar es, uno de los placeres que más educan a los niños" (corrijanme si me equivoco pero aquí *jugar* es un sustantivo porque lo precede un artículo).

Pero no conozco o no me doy cuenta de ninguna palabra que pueda ser, o ser usada, tanto como adjetivo, sustantivo o verbo.

¿Existen palabras en español que puedan ser usadas tanto como adjetivos, sustantivos y verbos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sustantivo:

> Recibí un hermoso **presente** de parte de mis suegros.

Adjetivo:

> El público **presente** en la sala aplaudió de pie.

Verbo:

> Es necesario que mañana usted se **presente** en el ministerio.

Answer (score 4):

Ya se han mencionado las palabras titular y circular.  De hecho, las palabras acabadas en "ar" nos proveen muchos ejemplos excelentes, de los que cabe mencionar dos otras.

La palabra "molar" cumple los requisitos. Se usa como [sustantivo o adjetivo](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/molar) con el siguiente significado:

> Se aplica al diente situado en el extremo de la mandíbula de los
>   mamíferos cuya función es triturar los alimentos

Pero tambien se usa como verbo, con otra aceptacion:

> Ser una cosa del agrado de una persona.

Obviamente hay otros significados, por ejemplo los relacionados con la quimica, pero estos son suficientes para establecer que se utiliza como verbo, sustantivo, y adjetivo.

Otro ejemplo es [militar](https://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=PFlXEFf%7CPFlagiY). Para demostrar esto necesitamos solo una oracion:

> El militar es militar; por eso tiene que militar.

Es decir:

> El soldado no es civil; por eso tiene que servir en la guerra.

Como sustantivo significa a alguien que sirva en las fuerzas armadas, como adjetivo las cosas propias de dichas fuerzas y como verbo varias cosas incluyendo hacer la guerra, literalmente o figurativamente.

Answer (score 2):

Quizá haya alguna palabra en español que se pueda usar como adjetivo, sustantivo y verbo, pero no se me ocurre ninguna.

Unos cuantos verbos en infinitivo en español pueden ser usados como sustantivos de género masculino, aunque no siempre el significado es el que esperamos: *el despertar* es la acción de despertar, pero *el ser* puede ser sinónimo de *el ente, la cosa*. Las frases infinitivas, con o sin argumentos (objetos directos, complementos) funcionan como frases nominales (similares a sustantivos). Hay sustantivos que son iguales a formas verbales, como *el canto, la busca, el camino, la tapa*), pero esto no es exactamente de lo que estamos hablando, creo.

Con los adjetivos es más difícil porque en español no se puede hacer lo que hace el inglés en expresiones como "water sports", "ground rules", "cat food", "airplane ticket" y tantas otras. En español los sustantivos, para modificar a otro sustantivo, tienen que ser transformados en adjetivos o bien en frases preposicionales, generalmente con *de* o *para*: *deportes acuáticos*, *reglas básicas*, *comida para gatos*, *billete de avión*.

Excepcionalmente se hace algo parecido a lo del inglés, generalmente por un calco del propio inglés, [modificando un sustantivo con otro directamente](https://www.rae.es/consultas/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas): *hombre araña* ("spider man"), *copia pirata* ("pirate copy"), *palabra clave* ("key word"). Estos pares sustantivo-sustantivo son expresiones idiomáticas más o menos fijas. La mayoría de los sustantivos no pueden usarse de esta forma.

Por lo anterior es muy difícil encontrar una palabra en español que pueda funcionar sin cambios como sustantivo, verbo y adjetivo.

Comment: En copia pirata, pirata no es adjetivo? De ser así, se me ocurre que la palabra copia podría ser un ejemplo. Por ejemplo la copia (sustantivo), copia ese dibujo (verbo), y tipo copia (adjetivo)

Comment: Los sustantivos que pueden funcionar de esa manera son pocos. Lo que quise decir en la respuesta es que no se puede, por regla, hacer en español lo que se hace libremente en inglés con los sustantivos que modifican a otros sustantivos.

Comment: ¿Qué tal **circular**?

Comment: cualquier adjetivo puede ser utilizado como sustantivo, el problema es encontrar un adjetivo que sea tambien un verbo.

Comment: @Jdamian Pensaba en palabras cuyo significado sea obvio cuando cambian de sustantivo a verbo o a adjetivo (como *water* en "clear water" - "water sports" - "water the plants"). Las tres acepciones de *circular* no tienen esa relación clara. (¿Quién se imaginaría que una circular es una carta?).

Comment: @Jdamian ¡Gran palabra! Deberías redactar una respuesta con ella, indicando las tres acepciones.

Comment: Y el ejemplo con la palabra copia está bien o está mal? Y están relacionados en significado

Comment: No es cuestión de si está bien o mal, sino de si se puede considerar que "copia" es un adjetivo. Para mí no, pero estas cosas no son una ciencia exacta. "Pirata" sí puede ser adjetivo.

Comment: Otro caso podría ser "titular": titular un libro (verbo), el titular de un diario (sustantivo) y miembro titular (adjetivo).

Comment: @gustavson ese cumple con lo que dice el titular de la pregunta. Se podria publicar como respuesta .

Answer (score 2):

Otro ejemplos serían «pago» o «puesto».

Ya que un participio es a la vez forma verbal (en construcción compuesta) y adjetivo, y los adjetivos suelen nominalizarse con facilidad (especialmente los que vienen de verbos para representar lo que se ha [verbo]-ado.

Answer (score 0):

La palabra "nominalización" se usa para indicar el empleo de un adjetivo o verbo como si fuera un sustantivo.  [enlace](https://www.gramaticas.net/2012/05/ejemplos-de-nominalizacion.html).

Hay muchos casos donde existe un sustantivo que tiene el mismo origen que un verbo o adjetivo, pero donde las formas de las palabras difieren.  No hay semejante fenómeno en el inglés, donde la misma palabra se emplea como verbo o adjetivo o sustantivo, con pocas excepciones.

Answer (score 0):

Hueco, puesto, roto, claro, fresco, son adjetivo y sustantivo... solo es cuestión de pensar un poco más.

Como verbo además de sustantivo y adjetivo: “dicho” es verbo, adjetivo y sustantivo. Es cuestión de pensar.